# not able to change class within id although no errors

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why my extraInfo variable isn't being printed out onto the webpage.

The information is being retrieved correctly (I've tested this with alert()) but I just cannot figure out why it isn't replacing the span text with the returned value.

I've tried sending it out wrapped in P tags too and although no errors come out, it still doesn't amend the text.

https://github.com/ralam87/Quote-generator

Where am I going wrong?

```
document.getElementById("source").getElementsByClassName("citation")[0] = extraInfo;
```

Comment: What is extraInfo supposed to be? Right now it would have to be a HTMLElement. If it contains HTML try [0].innerHTML = extraInfo;

Answer (score 0):

I gone through your example.

**Note:** when you are trying to assign the citation to first element with `.citation` class that time the there are no elements present with the class `citation` because it get replaced when you set the value to source element just before citation `document.getElementById("source").innerHTML = author;`.

This are possible solution

1. change this `document.getElementById("source").getElementsByClassName("citation")[0] = extraInfo;` to `document.getElementsByClassName("citation")[0].innerHtml = extraInfo;`
2. remove the `id` from `<p id="source">`
3. create another `<span> or <div> or <p>` element inside the existing `<p>` and assign the `id=source` to that inner element. for example `<p><span id="source"></span><span id="citation"></span></p>`.

If you want to have the `,` after the source name then at the time of assigning the `document.getElementById("source").innerHTML = author + ',';`.

> If you allow me i can also contribute this directly to you git
>   repository.